# Is it possible to have HTML inside Google chart tick?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have some custom ticks:

```
...
hAxis: {
          ticks: [
            {v: 1, f: '1'},
            {v: 2, f: '2'},
            {v: 3, f: '<strong>3</strong>', isHtml: true},
            {v: 4, f: '4'},
          ],
...
```

Check #3 with isHtml flag. This flag is *not* valid, *not* documented and is *not* working. There is similar flag for tooltip and it works well.

**Is there any way to have HTML inside tick while using official API?**

I'm thinking about a workaround to run some js after chart is loaded and edit to whatever style needed, but would be best just render html together with chart.

I use column chart. Docs: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart

Comment: html ticks are not supported...

Comment: Hopefully, this will be supported in near future releases

Comment: Any update on this?